# Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve y=3x^2-x^3 at the point (3,0)

Tags: calculus

So far I have this, not sure what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$$(a+b)^n\ne a^n+b^n$$ in general for integer $n\ge2$

$$(3+h)^2=(3^2+2\cdot3\cdot h+h^2)$$

$$(3+h)^3=(3^3+3\cdot3^2\cdot h+3\cdot3\cdot h^2+h^3)$$

Answer (score 0):

Original equation: $3x^2-x^3=y$
First derivative of y with respect to x:  $6x-3x^2={{dy}\over{dx}}$
Substitute 3 for x: $6×3-3×3^2=-9$
Point-slope form of line: $-9={y\over{x-3}}$
Final form of tangent to point $(3\mid 0)$ in locus of equation:
$9x+y=27$

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense- I forgot to use dy/dx!